# How to convert a pd.Series to a pd.DataFrame where indices are dates and columns are time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pd.Series whose index are pd.DataTimeIndex. I would like to convert the 1D series to a DataFrame whose indices are the dates and columns are time of each data. Something like this:

```
            08:01:00  08:02:00  08:03:00  08:04:00  08:05:00
2011-04-04      2.50      2.65      2.65       2.7       2.8
2011-04-05     -4.30     -4.45     -4.70      -4.6      -5.0
2011-04-06     25.75     26.30     26.50      26.7      27.1
2011-04-07      1.15     -0.45     -0.45      -0.4       0.2
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
s.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([s.index.date,s.index.time])
df=s.unstack()
df
            08:01:00  08:02:00  08:03:00  08:04:00  08:05:00
2011-04-04      2.50      2.65      2.65       2.7       2.8
2011-04-05     -4.30     -4.45     -4.70      -4.6      -5.0
2011-04-06     25.75     26.30     26.50      26.7      27.1
2011-04-07      1.15     -0.45     -0.45      -0.4       0.2
```

Comment: or without modifying `s`: `s.set_index([s.index.date, s.index.time]).unstack()`.